# Visual Studio for Windows Media Foundation

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio, ms-media-foundation

I am going to build sample application using Windows Media Function, but I am confused with Visual Studio version that need to be used. Also how I can start with this sample application. Do I need to download Windows Developer SDK for building this sample? Also what tools I need to use to build UI components.

I want to build sample application for playing local video file.

Answer (score 1):

To develop classic/desktop applications using Media Foundation API it is sufficient to use simplest edition of Visual Studio, e.g. [Visual Studio 2015 Community Edition](https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/) along with [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) (do not get confused by "Windows 10" in the title, appropriately built applications can run in Windows XP and more recent). You will have to look up desktop application samples in older Windows SDK versions up to version 7.1, since version 8 they were omitted (later they were put online [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/master/Samples/Win7Samples/multimedia/mediafoundation)). At the same time, there are also [newer Media Foundation samples](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mediasdkstuff/2015/05/29/list-of-windows-10-developer-preview-uwp-audio-video-camera-and-graphics-samples/) available in the format of Windows 10 UWP applications, you can built them with the mentioned toolset as well.